# Master and Slave system OS version

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing

I'm trying to create my own hadoop clister. My all data nodes have installed `ubuntu 18` and Name node is having `ubuntu 14`.

Is it mandatory that Name node and Data nodes should have same version of OS .. ?

Comment: Are you doing this to learn Hadoop or are you planning to use it for the long term?

Comment: @tk421 To learn ..!

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to have the same major version at least to avoid kernel vulnerabilities. If you come across these low level issues, they are very difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

As @piyush-p said, it's not recommended but as long as you are running the same Java version across all the hosts you should be okay.  You probably won't want to
do this if you are using a commercial distribution of Hadoop (HDP, Cloudera) as their
respective setup tools (Ambari, Cloudera Manager) will probably disallow this.

See [HDP Support for mix of OS Releases within a cluster](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/HDP-Support-for-mix-of-OS-Releases-within-a-cluster/m-p/97315) for more details.